# Entering data in an input and then displaying just the text entered elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a checkout page and I cannot figure out how to do the following. When the customer enters their shipping information, I want to display that same information further down the page in a confirmation section. I will not be submitting the information until the customer places the order, so there is no way to echo this information as I won't be submitting to my db until after they submit it.

I looked into this and I see things with a data-copy function and that is basically what I need except I do not want the copied data to show up in an input field. I just want it to display the text.

So if I had the following field:

Shipping street:
123 Main St.

I would want the 123 Main St to show up in a different section of the page.

I tried doing the data-copy function and I couldn't even get that to work. I'm not sure if this is the best method to use for this. I do not want the copied data to be editable. I have disabled that from my code.

I tried doing this:

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
        <div class="center"><input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="name" name="ShipToFullname" required>          </div>
</div>
```

This is the confirmation part farther down the page:

```
<p><input type="text" class="preview" id="name" disabled></p>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".preview").keyup(function() {
     var ElemId = $(this).data('copy');
    $("#"+ElemId).val($(this).val());
 });
});
```

Is there a better way I can do this and most importantly an input field not show up with the copied data?

UPDATED CODE

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
        <div class="center"><input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" required></div>
    </div>
```

Confirmation part

```
<p>Shipping to:</p>
    <p><div class="preview" id="name"></div></p>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".preview").on('keyup', function() {
$($(this).data('copy')).html($(this).val());
 });
});
```

Comment: try using another element ID other than `name` - and also try `$(this).attr('data-copy');`, might work

Comment: if you dont want the mirrored data to appear in a `<input>`, make a `<div>` instead and set `.html($(this).val());`

Comment: I need the initial input to be an input. I cannot have the copied data be an input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Note that `data-copy="name"` should now be `data-copy="#name"` for it to work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".preview").on('keyup', function() {
    $($(this).data('copy')).html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field">
  <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" required>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

Your name is:
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is and your code snippet works just as I want it to except I cannot get my data to show up at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters but in my input part, when I type data-copy it stays black like it is not a function.

Comment: Check my data-copy, it has a hash in front now(`data-copy="#name"`), that is a requirement for it to work, my bad, didn't pointed it out. You mean the editor display the data attribute as black? that may be because the data attributes arent "regular".

Comment: Yes they appear as black. I saw your hash and added that. Still nothing. I'm thinking this may be the reason my data isn't transferring?

Comment: Mmmmmh...black. Is the data-copy attribute in the page when you inspect the input with the console?

Comment: No errors display and in the console element it shows up orange just like all of the other atrtributes.

Comment: What happens if you type `$('#ShipToFullname').data('copy')` in the console? If it shows up ok, does the element where you want to copy the input has that id?

Comment: I just edited my question to show my current code. Not sure if I'm missing anything. Do I need any sort of on page loading function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79381/discussion-between-jselser-and-paul).

Answer (score 2):

Simply change

```
var ElemId = $(this).data('copy');
$("#"+ElemId).val($(this).val());
```

to

```
$('#name').val($('#ShipToFullname').val());
```

Basicaly it says to set the value of id `name`to the value of id `ShipToFullname`

Here the fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/9sgcydmg/1/

If you don't want to output the data in another input you can simply set an id to any html element and use instead:

$('#name').html($('#ShipToFullname').val());

Here the fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/89oeyq0h/

FINAL ANSWER : in it's most simple way, using jQuery, i would do something like this:

```
<input onkeyup="$('#name').html(this.value)" ... />
<p id='name'></p>

<input onkeyup="$('#addr').html(this.value)" ... />
<p id='addr'></p>

and so on...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oky005a0/

Comment: Two questions with this. I have multiple fields I want to do this for. Would I just list all of my fields in this $('#name').val($('#ShipToFullname').val()); with different ids? Also this is still showing an input field in the second part..

Comment: You can simply add another line inside the keyup(function() { }
heres another fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/ozb25xgv/2/